# Плавное изменение высоты блока

Tags: html, css

```
.block.post:hover {
    height: auto;
}

.block.post {
    max-height: 200px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

У меня у одного высота плавно не меняется? Как это исправить?

Comment: примените свойство transition

Comment: Не помогает, видимо надо как-то особенно это сделать

Comment: дал ответ с примером

Comment: А вы уверены, что `heigth: auto;` будет отличаться по высоте от вашего начального значения?

Comment: Не всегда, конечно но разве есть разница?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот работающий сниппет. Надо ставить высоту auto сразу, overflow: hidden, и регулировать высоту блока при наведении через max-height

```css
div {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
  transition: max-height 1.5s;
}

div:hover {
  max-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text</div>
```

Comment: Это то понятно, но как заставить его работать с атрибутом auto? У меня блок с неизвестной полной высотой. Т.Е при наведении он должен раскрываться по высоте содержимого.

Comment: ну и с auto мой пример работает - посмотрите

Comment: Оно не плавно происходит.. Сижу на Chrome последней версии..

Comment: Поправил вопрос.

Comment: да погодите вы. вы правите вопрос быстрее, чем я успеваю отвечать

Comment: он работал корректно без auto

Comment: Объясню теорию работы стиля: Есть блок с публикацией, часть которого скрыта (текста много), и при наведении постепенно появляется весь текст. Если текста мало, анимация не происходит (ибо стоит max-height), однако что-то пока не получается..

Comment: момент, с auto..

Comment: Сделал, работает плавно с auto

Comment: Насчет auto оно то понятно, однако я имел ввиду max-height: auto;
Т.Е если я не коснулся блока, он его высота равна допустим 250px, если же коснулся то он равен высоте текста.
Решил это тем что написал max-height: 1000px; работает, однако, если текст больше 1000 пикселей то он будет выглядеть не полным.