# Плавное увеличение высоты блока с неизвестным содержимым

Tags: css, вёрстка

Есть некий `div id="container"` в котором находится неизвестное количество контента. Например может быть 1 вложенный `div` а может быть 10. Свойства контейнера когда он скрыт :

```
#container{
    max-height: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Далее мне нужно его плавно развернуть :

```
#element:checked ~ #container{
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

Все нормально работает, но только пока `max-height` равно 500 или другое точное значение. Если выставить `auto` то высота не меняется вообще. Похожий вопрос уже был [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736786/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0) но ответ подразумевает знание точной высоты `div #container` а как быть если высота должна быть `auto` ?

```css
#container {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#element:checked ~ #container{
    max-height: 300px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapp">
<input type="checkbox" id="element"/>
<div id="container">
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: У тебя изначально должна быть видна 1 строчка?

Comment: @makcim512 `input` должен быть виден, остальное нет

Comment: Да не как! Если не известна высота трансформ не поймет на какую высоту открывать.

Comment: А не будет такого, что вдруг внутренности окажутся больше экрана и к ним надо будет добавить overflow: scroll ? Тогда по любому придется на JS делать)

Comment: @makcim512  поставь вместо высоты в px значение в `100%` и увидишь что  понимает, только переход резкий.

Comment: @Сергей Правильно открывать он будет! Но прикол в том что при width:100%; transition не может посчитать скорость. Ибо 100% понятие растяжимое)

Comment: @makcim512 очень хорошее замечание )

Comment: @makcim512 можно поставить значение `max-height` заранее огромным и больше чем нужно в 99.9% случаев но при этом и длительность `transition` выставить в 20s тоже заранее больше чем нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вместо % используйте vh - оно отталкивается от высоты окна браузера и часто очень помогает там, где % не срабатывает.

Answer (score 5):

Это конечно не то же самое, но можно сотворить что-то такое с трансформом =)

```css
#container {
    transform: translate(0,-50%)scaleY(0);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#element:checked ~ #container{
   transform: translate(0,0);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapp">
<input type="checkbox" id="element"/>
<div id="container">
  <div>
  <a href="#">text</a>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

Ну и вот такой вариант могу предложить

```css
#container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container > * {
    transform: translate(0,-100%);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#element:checked ~ #container > * {
   transform: translate(0,0);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapp">
  <input type="checkbox" id="element"/>
  <div id="container">
    <div>

      <div>
        <a href="#">text</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>text</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>text</span>
      </div>
        <div>
        <span>text</span>
      </div>
        <div>
        <span>text</span>
      </div>
        <div>
        <span>text</span>
      </div>
        <div>
        <span>text</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>text</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Еще можно  `max-height: 100vh;` (vh = viewport height):

```css
#container {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#element:checked ~ #container{
    max-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapp">
<input type="checkbox" id="element"/>
<div id="container">
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А можно сделать не затрагивая дочернии элементы контейнера ?

Comment: @Сергей я подумаю...

Comment: @Сергей Не партесь, не выйдет! Великие умы ломали голову над этим вопросом. Сделайте через JS

Comment: На самом деле мне подходит костыль когда `max-height` в 10000px и время анимации секунд 20. Внешне вполне адекватно работает, но спасибо за интересные решения.

Comment: Одна проблема с таким подходом - сворачивание обратно происходит с задержкой тк браузер начинает реально соврачивать все 100000px и хотя это не заметно, но задержка перед плавной анимацией присутствует. Можно только указать 0s для анимации сворачивания.

Comment: @Сергей просто не надо сворачивать то что больше экрана таким образом, можно всегда задать `max-height:100vh`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ `max-height:100vh` вместо `max-height:100%` именно то что нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Вам и не нужно знать конечную высоту, задайте просто раскрывашке height:auto; и max-height побольше.

```css
#container {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#element:checked ~ #container{
    max-height: 1000px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapp">
<input type="checkbox" id="element"/>
<div id="container">
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>text</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это будет неравномерно.

Comment: @Qwertiy в смысле?

Comment: если контейнер в высоту 200px то пролетит очень быстро (как на 1000px) а если высота больше 1000 то вообще не все попадет.

Comment: max-height можете сделать хоть 100000. И я так понимаю, что Qwertiy, как и вы, говорил про неравномерность анимации?

Comment: если сделать 100000 то анимации пользователь вообще не увидит. ведь что бы пройти 100000 за 1s нужна очень большая скорость.

Comment: единственно что можно сделать это поставить 100000px и transition в 22s

Comment: Высота не становится 100К пикселей сразу же, это предельное значение при огромном кол-ве контента.

Comment: вместо % используйте vh - оно отталкивается от высоты окна браузера и часто очень помогает там, где % не срабатывает.

Comment: @Инквизитор это именно то что нужно! Можете оформить это как ответ.